# Getting the version number (!) of the most recent release of an artifact

Tags: rest, nexus, sonatype

for a hubot script i need to determine the most recent release version of an artifact.
All artifacts are deployed to a sonatype nexus, so i want to use the nexus api to do that.

Is there a way to get the nexus api to return just the version number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the Nexus rest API to get latest artifact version for given groupid/artficatid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911620/using-the-nexus-rest-api-to-get-latest-artifact-version-for-given-groupid-artfic)

Comment: @MarkO'Connor the difference this question and the referenced question is i want to know the VERSION without downloading.

Comment: Try this one instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211385/oss-nexus-how-to-use-rest-api-to-retrieve-last-version-as-a-text/12223091#12223091

Comment: @MarkO'Connor works great. thank you. if you want an accepted answer just create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211385/oss-nexus-how-to-use-rest-api-to-retrieve-last-version-as-a-text/12223091#12223091) i can use the "resolve" function that returns all information about an artifact i could ever want

For Example:

https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/resolve?r=cometd-snapshots&g=org.cometd.jetty&a=cometd-jetty-client&v=1.0-SNAPSHOT&e=jar

Note:

- the type (e) is optional, the default value is jar
- it is possible to get a json result, but in case of errors or non existing artifacts the result is ALWAYS html
- the versions LATEST and RELEASE are supported

Comment: hi, is possible to do that without a Nexus plugin? thank you